# Multimarkdown syntax plugin for vim

Tags: vim, markdown

I notice vim as of 7.3 has builtin support for markdown syntax.  Is there anywhere available a syntax plugin for multimarkdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one now: [vim-multimarkdown](https://github.com/jngeist/vim-multimarkdown)

Comment: Which is, according to the ReadMe, "Still in early, halfhearted development" and only has one commit...

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe a Vim multimarkdown syntax plugin exists as of today.

The only multimarkdown syntax plugin that I am aware of is for [TextMate](http://macromates.com/) and is available on [github](https://github.com/fletcher/MultiMarkdown).